# Where do I store sensitive data in a Node.js app on GitHub deployed to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables

Right now my app is still in dev mode and my sensitive data like database username/password, keys, secrets etc. are stored in a config.js file.

This file is part of the Github repository of this app like the rest of its files. It's a private repository (but not a local one) where only I have access right now.

Whenever I update a file locally and push it to Github, Github then pushes the updates to Heroku which updates the live Node.js app.

I don't want my config.js file to be part of this repository anymore. i.e. I don't want it to be accessible anywhere other than from within Heroku.

In other words I want to upload that file directly to the Heroku directory where my app is stored.

Whenever, I want to update any of my sensitive data I will have to go and find that file in the Heroku directory and update/edit it from there.

Isn't that the best/safest way to store that data? Is there another way?

I know about environment variables but I don't want to have to set them everytime I start my app, that's why I want to retrieve my sensitive data from a stored file.

Comment: just add your config to gitignore

Comment: That's a good idea. Hadn't thought of that. But wouldn't it better if that file didn't exist even on my local machine (where the commits take place)? I mean Heroku isn't accessible by anyone other than myself where as keeping it in my local machine available for anyone to see is risky right ?

Comment: as long as your local machine is properly secure then it shouldnt be an issue, enabling RSA authentication and disabling password authentication via SSH would be more than adequate for hobby projects

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot redFIVE! (it's not actually a hobby project - it's simply in dev mode right now but it will go live at some point..)

Comment: Good luck, also, you can keep a renamed blank config file in your git repo as a template. just call it something like `config.js.temp`

Comment: I have yet to have an unauthorized access using RSA auth in years of running exposed linux boxes so you should be ok